# How do I create a javascript function that add html elements dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to creat a javascript function that adds new html elements, with new ID's for each element. for example this form; To let the user submit languages he can speak and his level on each one. But he can add a new input to type other languages if he speaks many.

```
<form id="form">
Language spoken1: <input id="language1">
Level: <input id="level1">
<form>
<input type="button" value="add new language" id="add" onclick="myFunction">
```

To get a result like this

```
<form id="form">
Language spoken1: <input id="language1">
Level: <input id="level1">
Language spoken2: <input id="language2">
Level: <input id="level2">
<form>
<input type="button" value="add new language" id="add" onclick="myFunction">
```

And when he submit result like this will be on the page

Language spoken1: English, level: native
Language spoken2: Spanish, level: good

Comment: There's a million technologies and ways to achieve that. Pick one, give it a shot, then come back with a specific programming problem, if you encounter any.

Comment: i'm newbie bro, just tell me the topic of that technology and i will, is it html dom, appendchild and setatribute? im tryin

Comment: Without a server-side technology like login on a webserver and a database the changes a user does are lost as soon as they reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you click the button, it will create two input elements, count the existing inputs and find the number of new input-ids. I've also added auto-focus to input, after adding... and delete button)

```js
(function(){
  
let form = document.getElementById('form');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function(){
  let lang  = document.createElement('input');
  let level = document.createElement('input');
  let number = document.querySelectorAll('#form input').length / 2 + 1;

  lang.id = 'language' + number;
  level.id = 'level' + number;

  lang.placeholder = 'Language spoken' + number;
  level.placeholder = 'Level';

  form.innerHTML += '<br>';
  form.appendChild(lang);
  form.appendChild(level);

  lang.focus();
});
  
document.getElementById('delete').addEventListener('click', function(){
  let inp = document.querySelectorAll('#form input');
  if(inp.length == 2){ return; }
  /* removing last two elements */
  inp[inp.length-1].remove();
  inp[inp.length-2].remove();

  let br = document.querySelectorAll('#form br');
  br[br.length-1].remove();
});
  
})();
```

```css
#delete {
  color: white;
  background-color: #c00;
  border: 2px solid #c00;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#form {white-space: inherit;}
input {margin: 2px 5px;}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="language1" placeholder="Language spoken1"><input id="level1" placeholder="Level">
</form>

<br>

<input type="button" value="add a new language" id="add"> 
<input type="button" value="X" id="delete">
```

Any questions?)

Comment: Thanks bro☺ It is not 100% but at least i can go from there and try more.  I need the submate or save button to save it and desplay the input value on a <ul>.... is it easier to make such as this function on php or other backends? I didn't get there yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML

```js
document.getElementById("form").innerHTML='Language spoken1:<input id="language1"> Level: <input id="level1"><br> Language spoken2: <input id="language2"> Level: <input id="level2">'
```

```html
<form id="form">
 
</form>
<input type="button" value="add new language" id="add" onclick="myFunction">
```

> 

Comment: it didn't work bro i'll study js qnd html dom more, iwas just excited to make it as soon as possible;)